# Cannot import tensorflow: No module named 'tensorflow'

Tags: python, import

getting the below when trying to import tensorflow:

```
import tensorflow
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>      File
>   "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_import_hook.py",
>   line 20, in do_import
>       module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs) ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'

Answer (score 0):

did you use `pip install tensorflow` in your command line before trying to import it?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Windows. You need to install **Python x64**(64bit) version from [here](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-362/).

Once that's done you need to start command line (Windows + R) enter cmd.

In that cmd type `pip install tensorflow`.

Then you can restart your shell and test it with

```
import tensorflow
```

If you're on Ubuntu(Linux) then `pip3 install tensorflow` will do the job.