# an error (ImportError: No module named tensorflow) in spyder

Tags: python

i got this

---

ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
1 get_ipython().magic('matplotlib inline')
2 import numpy as np
----> 3 import tensorflow as tf
4 from tensorflow.contrib import rnn
5 import data_loader

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question [Cannot import tensorflow: No module named 'tensorflow'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52054135/cannot-import-tensorflow-no-module-named-tensorflow?rq=1)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python error "ImportError: No module named"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338768/python-error-importerror-no-module-named)

Answer (score 0):

Open your terminal and write:
`pip install tensorflow`